# Implement BSD style progress bar in C?

Tags: c, printf, sleep, backspace

I'm trying to make a simple progress bar like FreeBSD does in its booting screen , displaying / , | , \ , - recursively , but the following code got now output at all

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ( int argc , char **argv )
{
    char arrows[4] = { '/' , '|' , '\\' , '-' };
    int i = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf ( "%c" , arrows[i] );

        if ( i > 3 ) 
            i = 0;
        else
            i ++;

        sleep (1);
        printf ( "\b" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string? (in C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not flush the output, so it will only be buffered and not flushed to the terminal until the buffer is full.

Add the following line after the first `printf`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell right away, but keep in mind that arrays in size go from `0` to `size - 1`. Which means this:

```
if ( i > 4 ) 
    i = 0;
else
    i ++;
```

Is an off-by-one error. It should be either `i > 3` or  `i >= 4`.

As for your actual problem, it's probably because the stream isn't flushed.